# keys in request when web scraping

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

this has to be a very stupid question. I'm following a little tutorial on how to use requests and beautifulSoup and, in the example, one has:

```
# Build a dictionary containing our form field values
# http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries
form_data = {
    'name':'Romney', # committee name field
    'type':'P',      # committee type is P for Presidential
    'frmtype':'F3P', # form type
}

esponse = requests.post('http://query.nictusa.com/cgi-bin/dcdev/forms/', data=form_data)
```

My question is, how am I supposed to know the value of the keys?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean the keys of the `form_data` dictionary, you need to know the documentation of the API - that's where the necessary options to a HTTP request are defined. I can't find the docs for the service you are querying, but for example these are the [Facebook API docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/).

You can inspect exactly what are you sending for example, if you start a dummy host in a terminal:

```
$ nc -l 9999
```

and send your request to it:

```
>>> requests.post('http://localhost:9999', data=form_data)
```

netcat shows it received the following POST request:

```
POST / HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:9999
Content-Length: 30
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, compress
Accept: */*
User-Agent: python-requests/1.2.0 CPython/2.7.2 Darwin/12.4.0

frmtype=F3P&type=P&name=Romney
```

where the last line is your dictionary encoded by the requests library.

It's even simpler for parameters that can be encoded in the request url, which can be printed directly from Python (note the `params` constructor argument).

```
>>> req = requests.Request('POST', 'http://localhost:9999', params=form_data).prepare()
>>> rint(req.url)
http://query.nictusa.com/cgi-bin/dcdev/forms/?frmtype=F3P&type=P&name=Romney
```

Comment: I see, thanks a lot. So, in principle, if I don't have the API I could inspect the html document and find out what the names of the keys should be?

Comment: For some things, yes - if you e.g. want to automatically fill in web forms (where [markup](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_method.asp) defines the HTTP methods), but that only applies to simple web scraping. For real "headless" API's (that don't have a HTML document, but rely purely on e.g. JSON and HTTP methods) it would be hunting in the dark. Usually, if you want to rely on an API for your application, you would look for good documentation in it.